# How to use Encryption/Decryption to send encrypt data using post (JSON) method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, web-services

how to send the password,bank account, credit card information using JSON POST method,We cant send it as plain text. How to use encryption/Decryption method for sending this highly important data?

Three major problem :

1. How to encrypt data ? (Data means password,bank account, credit card information).
2. How to send this encrypt data using web service (JSON format)?
3. How to retrieved  this data from server and decrypt ?

Comment: This is such a massively broad question, there's no way to give you a detailed answer, and you're essentially asking us to write code for you to this end. Please first do some research (very basic stuff, really, that can be answered with a search engine), and then come back if you have specific technical questions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to do it on your server because there are no details about it, but you should have a SSL certificate. On the iPhone side to encrypt/decrypt something use the following:

```
NSString *stringToEncrypt = "Secure Info Here";
NSData* data = [stringToEncrypt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [data EncryptWithKey:@"key_you_want_to_use"];
NSLog(@"Encrypted data: %@", encryptedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant send bank information and credit card data of a user. Apple will reject your application when submitting to Appstore